# Eclipse Ubuntu JApplet Missing Title bar

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, applet, window

Good Evening,

I am running Eclipse on a 64 bit Distro of Ubuntu 11.04. I am programming a JApplet and using the Eclipse built in Applet Viewer when I compile and run my code. The problem is that the Applet Viewer window has no title bar or close bar, so I can not reposition the window or close the applet. (I can still close the applet by clicking the stop process button back in the Eclipse IDE)

Does anyone have any suggestions on fixing this?

Thank you,